# R/GIS: How to subset a shapefile by a lat-long bounding box?

Tags: r, gis

I want to subset out a shapefile (the .shp and associated files are [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1791181/asia_rivers.zip)) into another one bounded by a set of coordinates, say between longs [80,90] and lats [20,30], and then write this out as another shapefile. If I use the `maptools` package:

`df = readShapeLines("/path/asia_rivers.shp")`

and then look at the structure of the file with `as.data.frame(df)`, I can't find any obvious way of subsetting by coordinates. I *can* use the `PBSmapping` package to subset:

```
df = importShapefile("/path/asia_rivers.shp")
df_sub = subset(df, X>=80 & X<=90 & Y >=20 & Y <=30)
```

but then I can't seem to be able to coerce this into a `SpatialLines` data frame which can be exported via `writeSpatialShape()` in `maptools`. I keep getting this error: `Error in PolySet2SpatialLines(df_sub) : unknown coordinate reference system`. Surely I am missing something very basic and there should be an easy way of subsetting geo-data by geo-coordinates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
library(rgeos)
rivers <- readWKT("MULTILINESTRING((15 5, 1 20, 200 25), (-5 -8,-10 -8,-15 -4), (0 10,100 5,20 230))")
bbx <- readWKT("POLYGON((0 40, 20 40, 20 0, 0 0, 0 40))") 

rivers.cut <- gIntersection(rivers, bbx)

plot(rivers, col="grey")
plot(bbx, add=T, lty=2)
plot(rivers.cut, add=T, col="blue")
```

Comment: The problem is not in plotting, but in subsetting in a format which can be exported as a shapefile.

Comment: Did you try to read your shapefile, intersect it with a an appropriate bounding box using gIntersection and then export the it, e.g. with maptools::writeShapeLines? I only plotted it to show you that the lines have been trimmed with dummy data, since the shape file you provided is not valid (a shapefile consists of more than just a *.shp file; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile).

Comment: Hi jmsigner... Sorry, my bad. I changed the link to the zipped folder which contains the original .dbf, .lyr, .prj, .sbn, .sbx, .shp, and .shx files. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, given the size of the shapefile, I would preprocess the data in a GIS or with ogr2ogr from gdal. The following just took a few seconds on my computer: ogr2ogr -spat 80 20 90 30 asisa_rivers_cut.shp asia_rivers.shp

Comment: Oh boy! Looks like this is going to be a long walk :-) Thanks for gIntersection tip, jmsigner. One thing... Could you please tell me why when I do gIntersection(SpatialPolygon, SpatialLinesDataFrame), the result is simply of class SpatialLines (which cannot be exported with writeSpatialShape())?

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been answered, but I think you can do exactly what you want using `PBSmapping`. `PBSmapping` has a function to clip Polysets (for polygon and lines data) so you can try:

```
df <- importShapefile("/path/asia_rivers.shp")
df_sub <- clipLines(df, xlim = c(80 , 90) , ylim = c(20 , 30), keepExtra = TRUE )
dfSL <- PolySet2SpatialLines( df_sub )
```

The keep extra allows you to keep non-standard columns when you do the clipping (I assume for attribute data).

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
library(raster)

s <- shapefile("/path/asia_rivers.shp")

sub <- crop(s, extent(80, 90, 20, 30))

shapefile(sub, 'cropped_rivers.shp')
```